# Checking local Maven repository checksums

Tags: maven, checksum

Is there any existing tool which checks the SHA-1 checksums of the artifacts in a local Maven repository? I'd like to check the whole repository with one command.

Comment: @XaviLópez: No. For the interesting artifacts I did it a couple of shell commands. Anyway, I've left this question here hoping that somebody writes a shell script for that one day.